# Sign in form with bootstrap, express and node.js

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm pretty new to node.js and express so I'm still trying to figure out the basic functinality. I have a simple sing in form. I want that once I hit the sign in button another html page loads and a node.js function is called. How is the best way to do this?

Here is my form code.

```
  <form action="/create_dialog" method="post" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</input>
  </form>
```

With this code I succesfully navigate to the chat.html page once I click on the "Sign in" button. But what I want to do is also call a node.js function to create a file on the server when this happens and then to send the username variable that was entered to the chat.html page to display the name. This is the app.js code I have.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/create_dialog', function(req, res) {
  //res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.username + '".');
  console.log('You sent the name "' + req.body.username + '".');
    console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect('chat.html');
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I read somewhere that using this body-parser module could help me work with form data but I'm kind of lost on how to use it for a node.js function and then to send it to the chat.html page.

Edit 1: Updated the app.js code to add the routing function. Still can't access the variables since req.body is empty.

Edit 2: Also updated the form code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a link, you can use a input with the type `submit` like so:

```
<form action="/create_dialog" method="post" class="form-signin">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
  <label for="username"  class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="remember-me" type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
</form>
```

To then get the contents of the POST [request body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) in express you'd need a route like so:

app.js

```
app.post('/create_dialog', function(req, res){
  var username = req.body.username
  var password = req.body.password
  var remember = req.body.remember-me // 'on' (checked) or undefined (off)

 // With a veiw-engine - render the 'chat' view, with the username
 res.render('chat', {username: username})

})
```

views/chat.hbs (*assuming you use handlebars*)

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<p>Your username is: {{username}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To use [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) you need to use a view-engine such as jade, handlebars or hogan. If you're unsure how to set something like this up, you should look at a boilerplate app using express-generator (command line: `express --hbs chat-app`).

Comment: Ok now it is calling the app.post function correctly but I try to print the req.body.username and I get undefined even though I wrote some input text.

Comment: I printed the req.body and all I get is a {}

Comment: Are you defining the route before or after all the middleware (`app.use`...), it needs to be after. In your case, it should be just before the error handler.

Comment: Yes, the route is defined after the middleware.

Comment: I'm going to update my app.js code on the original code to show how it is written.

Comment: Try the edited answer (HTML), your html was incorrect (req.body maps named e.g `name="username"` keys to values). There is also no 'username' type that I'm aware of.

Comment: Worked great! Now, after I do the stuff I have to do with Node.js how can I load the chat.html page and make sure it receives the username value? Is my use of res.redirect ok? If so, how can I send the username value with it?

Comment: Updated my answer again, it's probbably best you look at an example express-generated app see http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html   so you can understand templating and rendering better.